# Parallel for is less efficient than serial?

Tags: c

I´ve been working on a small project for my college, with C and Openmp. To make it short, when trying to parallelize a `for` loop using the `#pragma omp parallel for` constructor, it ends up being way slower than the serial version, just by adding that, is a parallel version of odd-even sort that works with an array of integers

I found it has something to do with the threads accessing the memory location of the whole array each time they compare numbers and updating its own copy of it on the cache memory. But I don´t know how to fix it, so rather than updating the whole array, they just check the exact location of the integers they are comparing, I´m kinda new using Openmp so idk if there´s a clause of constructor for this kind of situation.

```
//version without parallel for
void bubbleSortParalelo(int array[], int size) {
    int i,j,first;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        first = i % 2;
        for (j = first; j < size-1 ; j+= 2){
            if (array[j] > array[j+1]){
                int temp = array[j+1];
                array[j+1]=array[j];
                array[j]= temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Version with parallel for, takes longer somehow

void bubbleSortParalelo2(int array[], int size) {
    int i,j,first;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        first = i % 2;
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (j = first; j < size-1 ; j+= 2){
            if (array[j] > array[j+1]){
                int temp = array[j+1];
                array[j+1]=array[j];
                array[j]= temp;

        }
    }
}
```

I want to make the parallel version at least as efficient as the serial one, because right now it takes like 10 times more, becoming worse with the more threads I use.

Comment: Your parallel for can't really run in parallel because the array is edited within the loop. BubbleSort can not operate at multiple positions at once, because the array might be edited in another thread at the same time

Comment: From the documentation: _"Loop iterations must be independent before the loop can be parallelized"_

Comment: Even after fixing the issues, for a small number of inputs, the parallel code may still run slower than serial just by virtue of the initial overhead to setup task coordination, etc.. It will be hard to measure appreciable differences with less than 1000 or so elements. After that, given bubble-sorts horrible efficiency characteristics, you should start seeing solid benefit as your array size grows.

Comment: Does [this](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mjb/cs575/Handouts/bubblesort.6pp.pdf) help?

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl No, the code is okay. There is no data race in the code (see the link above and note that j is incremented by 2). Axel: The problem is that OpenMP has overhead, and in this case, the overhead is greater than the gain from parallelization. If you use a very large array, the parallel code will be faster. PS: How are you measuring runtime? Incorrect measurement of runtime can also be a problem.

Comment: In the case of `size=20000` the parallel version is about 3 times faster. (Ryzen7 5800U, gcc 12.1 -fopenmp -O3 -mavx2)

Comment: @Laci Like this
`time1=omp_get_wtime();
            bubbleSort(array,i);
            time2=omp_get_wtime();
`
I rest time2 to time1 and the save it on a file, the just make a graphyc with ´python

Comment: I used the same method to measure runtime, if size>10000 the parallel version is faster for me.